# How far is my partition resize?

Tags: partitioning, xubuntu, system-installation, ubiquity

I'm in the process of installing Xubuntu, and it has been resizing the Windows XP Fat32 partition for a few hours. Is there any way to find out how far it is, or if it is even still partitioning, or hanging?

I'm just using the partitioner built into the Xubuntu installer.

The partman log says this:

```
parted_server: resize_partition(openfs=true)
parted_server: opened file system: yes
parted_server: try to check the file system for errors
/lib/partman/active_partition/80resize/do_option: error_handler: exception with type Timer
parted_server: OUT: Timer

parted_server: OUT: 0 (null)

parted_server: OUT: ready

parted_server: successfully checked
/lib/partman/active_partition/80resize/do_option: error_handler: exception with type Timer
parted_server: OUT: Timer

parted_server: OUT: 0 (null)
```

#### EDIT:

I can't hear the hard disk doing anything at all either, but I don't want to reboot.

Comment: Ah then open the progress details and see what stage it is on :) Resizing can take a VERY long time if the disc are full or near full.

Comment: @Rinzwind Progress details? It just has a spinning cursor

Comment: @Rinzwind Well, Ubiquity is using up ~75% CPU, and then do_option around 20%

Comment: Regarding the 'new problem': either you need to wait a bit longer for the screen to refresh OR it actually did crash at some point... I am -not- advising you to reboot but you probably will have to ;-)

Comment: @Rinzwind The process is still running... doesn't kill -USR1 give back some status for dd? Would that work for Ubiquity?

Comment: @Rinzwind Do you think I should reboot?

Comment: That could mess up your whole system. Got anything important on the system that is not saved elsewhere? if not: go for it :)

Comment: @Rinzwind Well, just the complete backup on sda5 ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up rebooting, and nothing was broken; it just hadn't been doing anything at all; the resize failed. Next time you're wondering what is happening, these points might help.

- Check the log of the partitioner (e.g. /var/log/partman), maybe you can understand enough (although I didn't this time)
- If you think something is happening, remember that resizing partitions takes *ages*, especially shrinking, and FAT32 (but also other files ystems)
- What is the output of lsblk? Just like the original scheme? Or different?
- How I decided it wasn't doing anything: Can you hear the hard disk working (or see the HDD LED blinking)? When resizing a partition, it should be working constantly. If, after half an hour, you still don't see any major disk activity, it isn't doing anything
- **Last point:** Use GParted to partition. It generally works much better than anything else, gives you output, and is to be recommended.

I hope this helps anyone who is in my (ex-)situation.